# Program showing fine in browser but fails to load resources in electron window

Tags: react-native, localhost, electron

Currently working on a project and everything was working fine. Then suddenly after rebooting from a power cut whilst working on said project, the electron application has since failed to load any online resources. It works perfectly fine when on a native browser using localhost but will fail to load any online resources on the electron application version.

Initially, I thought it was a firewall issue but changing settings has not changed anything. I've reset router/pc multiple times to no avail.

The error recieved for any online resource is **GET [URL] net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the error displayed in electron:
 [image]

Comment: Do you get an error in Electron and if so, can you show it?

Comment: @Jeppe I have included error shown in electron in post but you can also see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPibX.png